# L'accent en français, il se trouve où ?

Tags: prononciation

J'ai récemment entendu dire qu'en français toutes les syllabes sont accentuées avec la même force. Pourtant, en cours de français on m'a appris qu'on prononce toujours la dernière syllabe avec une force plus importante.

L'accent en français, il se trouve où ?

Answer (score 4):

J'ai écrit cette réponse en anglais aussi bien qu'en français au cas où je n'aie pas écrit assez clairement en français.

---

French words are stressed on their final syllable when they are isolated. In sentences, stress is determined by the end of the sentence, and not the end of each word.

In the sentence

> *Ceci est un nouveau livre*

the stress is on the word *livre*, and the word *nouveau* isn't stressed (and can even have secondary stress on its *first* syllable).

Whereas the sentence

> *Ce livre-là est nouveau*

ends with the word *nouveau* and therefore stresses the last syllable of *nouveau*.

---

La dernière syllabe des mots est accentuée quand les mots sont isolés. Quand on les prononce dans les phrases, l'accent est déterminé par la fin de la phrase, et pas par la fin du mot.

Dans la phrase

> *Ceci est un nouveau livre*

on accentue le mot *livre* et pas le mot *nouveau* (et on peut même accentuer la *première* syllabe par l'accent secondaire).

Cependant, dans la phrase

> *Ce livre-là est nouveau*

on accentue la dernière syllabe du mot *nouveau* parce qu'elle est à la fin de la phrase.

Comment: Good distinction between the two cases and both accurate.

Comment: _Dernière syllabe_ est ambigüe si on n'évoque pas les syllabes qualifiées de muettes au nord de la Loire. Quand on accentue _nouveau_, c'est _-veau_ qui est accentué. quand on accentue _livre_, c'est _li-_ qui est accentué.

Comment: Bref, un *e* facultatif ne porte pas l'accent.

Comment: @mouviciel Par définition, une syllabe ne peut pas être muette. Quand un mot se termine par un e muet (éventuellement accompagnée d'autres lettres non prononcées), sa dernière syllabe inclus la dernière voyelle prononcée.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, quand un *e* qui est muet en français "standard" est prononcé (accent méridional), l'accent tonique reste sur l'avant-dernière syllabe. Il peut en être de même pour d'autres voyelles finales que le *e* pour certains mots d'origine occitane ou italienne.

Comment: @jlliagre Intéressant ! Peux-tu en donner un exemple ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Des mots come *cacou*, *garri* et *pistou* sont le plus souvent accentués sur l'avant dernière syllabe à Marseille.

Comment: @jlliagre, Est-ce à dire que le nombre de syllabes d'un mot dépend de son contexte? Quelle est la dernière syllabe (et donc la position de l'accent tonique selon la réponse ci-dessus) de _libre_ dans: _logiciel libre_? et dans _Homme libre, toujours tu chériras la mer_?

Comment: @mouviciel Le mot *libre* isolé ou dans les deux propositions ci-dessus ne contient qu'une seule syllabe, il est donc facile de désigner la dernière. En revanche, l'expression *libre à vous* contient trois syllabes dont les deux premières "contiennent" libre.

Comment: @jlliagre, Dois-je donc en déduire qu'un alexandrin peut être composé de moins de douze syllabes?

Comment: @mouviciel Non, pas un alexandrin classique qui contient par définition douze syllabes. Il faut aussi tenir compte du fait que la prononciation des vers en poésie s'écarte souvent de la prononciation habituelle du français.

Answer (score 4):

Les deux sont vrais. En français, l'accent n'est pas significatif (et la longueur des syllabes non plus). Si on parle français avec toutes les syllabes à la même intensité et de même longueur, il n'y a pas d’ambiguïté ni de problème de compréhension. (Pour la longueur, il faut maintenir des pauses variables entre les mots ou groupes de mots, sinon ça nuit à la compréhension.)

(Par contre, même si le français n'est pas une langue tonale, la tonalité intervient. Les mots n'ont pas de tonalité, mais les phrases si. La règle de base est qu'une phrase finit par une tonalité descendante si elle est affirmative et montante si elle est interrogative.)

Mais si on n'accentue aucune syllabe, la voix a l'air très monotone. On comprend, mais on s'ennuie, ça peut être difficile de continuer à faire attention.

Le choix de syllabe à accentuer dépend plus de la phrase que du mot. Suivant la phrase, suivant le locuteur, et suivant si l'on parle plus ou moins vite, un mot peut se retrouver accentué ou non. C'est notamment vrai pour les mots d'une syllabes : certains ne sont presque jamais accentués (articles, pronoms dans la plupart des cas, prépositions), mais d'autres peuvent être accentués ou non en fonction du rythme de la phrase. En général, on n'aime pas avoir deux syllabes accentuées de suite, et on aime avoir au moins un accent secondaire toutes les trois ou quatre syllabes.

Pour les mots de plusieurs syllabes, on enseigne souvent que l'accent va en fin de mot (le E muet ne compte pas), mais ce n'est pas universel. Ce peut aussi être la première syllabe qui est accentuée ! Ce qui est assez vrai, c'est que dans les mots de trois ou quatre syllabes, les syllabes du milieu ne sont presque jamais accentuées. L'accentuation en début ou en fin de mot dépend des locuteurs et peut très bien varier d'une phrase ou d'une proposition à l'autre (mais rarement à l'intérieur d'une proposition).

En poésie, la règle d'accent en fin de mot est très marquée. En chanson, c'est beaucoup moins le cas : on peut sans problème mettre l'accent sur la première ou la dernière syllabe d'un mot suivant les besoins de la musique (par contre, il est plus rare d'accentuer une syllabe médiane).

Answer (score 1):

Nulle part. Vous avez raison, effectivement.

> [...] toutes les syllabes sont accentuées avec la même force.

Le français est une langue qualifiée de *[syllabique](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_syllabique)* ce qui signifie qu'elle se parle *sans accentuation porteuse de sens*.
Contrairement, par exemple, à l'anglais qui est une langue dite *[tonique/accentuelle](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_accentuelle)*.

---

Une exemple pour clarifier les choses. Un exemple connu de beaucoup d'écoliers en Francophonie.

*Illustrons ce en quoi consiste le concept d'une langue dite syllabique ou accentuelle*. En français, avoir

> Un professeur d'anglais

ou

> Un professeur anglais

sont deux phrases dont le sens découle ***uniquement*** de leur formulation. L'exemple ci-haut est caractéristique d'une langue dite syllabique.

En anglais, l'accentuation est porteuse de sens, en effet

> An english teacher

aura un sens différent selon que le locuteur insiste sur le mot *english*, ou le mot *teacher*.

Comme souligné par @Najib en commentaire, les accents impliqués ici et là ne sont qu'une manière de se faire entendre, induisent une musicalité, éventuellement représentative d'une région ou d'une appartenance sociale. Mais ce n'est ***aucunement*** une manière d'altérer le sens du propos tenu.

---

Aussi, si vous terminez vos phrases en insistant sur la dernière syllabe de manière machinale, vous ferez rire tout le monde. Vouz aurez juste l'air "bizarre". Est-ce clair?

---

J'en viens à réaliser suite au commentaire de @Greg ci-dessous, que nous ne parlons peut-être tout simplement pas de la même chose. Ce qui expliquerait au passage le fait que vous ayez pu entendre deux choses contradictoires. *In fine*,

> [...] toutes les syllabes sont accentuées avec la même force

Est relatif à la nature syllabique du Français.

> [...] toujours la dernière syllabe avec une force plus importante

Est relatif à l'emploi d'un accent expressif ou d'insistance.

Comment: On peut bien mettre un accent tonique plus fort pour insister sur certaines parties de phrase. Ex: "passe-moi le sel. Non, pas le poivre, je t'ai demandé le SEL" (les majuscules indiquent que ce mot reçoit alors un accent plus prononcé).

Comment: @Greg Je ne sais pas si on peut vraiment parler d'un accent. C'est juste dire le mot plus fort pour se faire entendre.

Comment: Il s'agit bien d'un accent: on parle alors d'accent *expressif* ou *d'insistance*, par opposition à l'accent *tonique* (donc mon premier commentaire n'était pas correct sur ce point, mais je ne peux plus le modifier...).

Comment: Suite à la modif: quand on dit que le français n'a pas d'accentuation *porteuse de sens*, on parle de l'accent tonique: il existe bel et bien en français, et se place sur la dernière syllabe d'une unité de sens (en général la phrase, cf. réponse de @b a) MAIS il n'est pas porteur de sens. C'est différent de l'accent expressif. Votre réponse semble suggérer qu'il n'y pas d'accent tonique en français, ce qui est faux.

Comment: @Greg. Après avoir relu les modifications faites à ma réponse, je vous confirme qu'elle n'a rien suggéré d'autre que le fait que le français n'était pas une langue tonique. Ce qui est vrai. Aussi, [cet article](https://www.agoravox.fr/tribune-libre/article/y-a-t-il-un-accent-tonique-en-42348) fait pas mal le tour de la question je trouve.

Comment: Being a tonic language has nothing to do with whether a language uses l'accent tonique. Unfortunate overlap of terminology. French doesn't have lexical tone. (Neither does English.) French doesn't have lexical stress but systematic stress. (English does have lexical stress: *re*cord vs. re*cord*.) But French does have pragmatic stress, i.e. stress employed at the prosodic level to indicate the point of interest or make a contrast. In that, there's no difference between the effect of moving the stress in "an English teacher" or "un professeur d'anglais" because English has it too.

Comment: @LukeSawczak "français [...] pas une langue tonique" et "il n'y pas d'accent tonique en français" sont effectivement deux choses bien différentes. Aussi, votre commentaire est suffisamment substantif pour faire l'objet d'une réponse. Pour laquelle je voterai(s) d'ailleurs, étant donné qu'elle éclaircit considérablement les choses.

Comment: @floquonsd'oùpepperx Systematic in that it's not a distinctive part of each lexical entry, but a single phonological rule. I'm not sure what's technically considered the phonetic expression of French stress; anecdotally and from listening to 2 recordings just now I'd say intensity and pitch, but [this paper](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00363971/document) says the former shows no appreciable difference and the later is only incidental, duration being the more reliable measure! Incidentally, I find Wikipedia's [summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Stress) good.