# Accent en début de mot : qui, où et quand ?

Tags: prononciation

Il semble communément établi qu'on met l'accent en fin de mot (ou de syntagme) en français. C'est ce qu'on trouve sur à peu près tous les sites de FLE. Pourtant, avant de répondre à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30044/laccent-en-fran%C3%A7ais-il-se-trouve-o%C3%B9), je me suis écouté parler et j'ai écouté un peu la radio, et j'ai entendu beaucoup d'accentuation en début de mot, plus ou moins fréquente suivant le locuteur. L'accent en fin de mot est majoritaire, mais pas au point de l'ériger en règle. Je ne trouve pas que l'accent en fin de mot soit plus naturel que l'accent en début de mot.

D'où viennent ces variations ? Est-ce que cela tient à un accent (régionale, social, …) ? Est-ce que cela dépend de l'emphase, du type de phrase, du niveau de langue, du type de discours ?

Et pourquoi affirme-t-on autant que l'accent va en fin de mot alors que la réalité est plus compliquée ? Est-ce une généralisation abusive de la poésie (j'ai l'impression qu'en poésie, l'accent en fin de mot est effectivement la règle — mais pas en chanson) ? Est-ce que c'était vrai autrefois mais pas en français moderne ?

Comment: In linguistics I learned that French stress at the lexical level is always final except *syllabes facultatives*. Word-initial stress would thus be [prosodic stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)#Prosodic_stress). I do hear a lot of this when listening to French. Even in the first 5 seconds of [this audiobook](https://youtu.be/ChFPwOo4f80)! « Le **pe**tit prince. » I think that stress marks a "block of interest". It occurs often with that function: 0:36 magnifique, 0:40 histoires, 0:51 sans, 1:08 premier, 1:10 dessin... Are the ones you hear of a very different nature?

Comment: @LukeSawczak I only did a very quick and biased survey (listened to a few different radio programs). This would probably have more prosodic stress than ordinary speech, and indeed there seemed to be a weak correlation between initial stress and emphasis. But there's more to it than this. Some speakers used initial stress in random-sounding patterns. What seems to be well-known in linguistics doesn't match reality — I think it describes the majority of speakers/circumstances, but it's not a universal rule by far.

Comment: Having now spent a bit more time actively listening for this on the radio, YouTube, podcasts, etc., I'm tempted to agree that either this "emphatic" usage is so ubiquitous that it has no particular meaning, or it's not the only reason the stress falls on the first syllable!

Answer (score 4):

Une expression neutre et calme laissera l’accent tonique en fin de mot, voire simplement en fin de phrase ou segment de phrase, mais il existe néanmoins toute une gamme de circonstances de la vie où cet accent, en général peu contrasté avec le reste de l’élocution, sera relégué à l’arrière-plan face à une intensité ajoutée ailleurs dans un mot ou une phrase.

En insistant sur un mot afin de l’affirmer à l’encontre d’un autre (spécifié ou sous-entendu):

- Je l’ai É-couté, et COM-pris. *(Pas dormi, comme vous semblez l’insinuer.)*
  *Comparez avec cette affirmation, que l’on sent bien plus neutre:* Je l’ai écouté et compris. *(Même si ce n’était pas facile.)*
- C’est PAR-fois le cas! *(Pas toujours)*
  C’est parfois le cas. *(Ça arrive à l’occasion)*
- C’est UNE manière de faire. *(Il y en a d’autres, peut-être même meilleures)*
  C’est une manière de faire. *(Ça fonctionne)*
- C’est LA manière de faire. *(Les autres solutions ne valent même pas la peine qu’on s’y attarde)*
  C’est la manière de faire. *(C’est ainsi que nous procédons)*

Parfois, cet accent se fera simplement sur une négation, généralement, mais pas toujours, exprimée par des mots courts en français. La négation se comprendra en contraste avec une affirmation contraire, qui pourra avoir ou ne pas avoir été exprimée auparavant.

- Je n’ai PAS fait ça!
- PER-sonne ne doit passer!

En d’autres circonstances, on accentuera dès la première syllabe pour marquer l’ampleur du terme utilisé, afin qu’il soit bien compris dans sa valeur la plus littérale et non comme l’exagération qu’il exprime parfois:

- Le canyon était GI-gantesque!
- Elle a été TEL-lement courageuse!
- IM-possible! JA-mais j(e n)’accepterai!
- C’était GÉ-nial!

Le troisième exemple, ci-dessus, propose une version familière et une alternative plus conforme aux normes grammaticales. Les deux pourraient être exprimées avec l’emphase indiquée sans sembler étranges. Il semble bien que si le niveau de langue puisse parfois changer le type d’emphase (plus traînant, par exemple, pour quelqu’un sous l’effet de l’alcool, moins marqué chez quelqu’un de fatigué, fort, bref et même parfois chantant pour un animateur de radio professionnel), la mobilité de l’accentuation est un phénomène qui s’observe à tous les niveaux de langue.

Une autre possibilité pour certains des exemples précédents qui laisserait de côté l’accentuation serait de bien détacher les syllabes et prononcer plus lentement, mais ce pourrait être perçu comme mou et peu vivant (d’ailleurs, la troisième phrase serait vraiment peu convaincante de cette manière, et la quatrième en souffrirait un peu aussi).

- Le canyon était gii-gaan-tees-queu.
- Elle a été teel-meent courageuse.

Les deux méthodes peuvent aussi se combiner, avec un effet plus heureux que le simple découpage des syllabes:

- Le canyon était GI-GAN-TES-que!

Même un professeur pourra mettre à profit cette mobilité de l’accentuation pour mieux transmettre l’importance d’une certaine notion, sans que cela ne doive être perçu comme ridicule ou inapproprié:

- CON-trairement à l’adition, la SOUSTRACTION n’est PAS commutative.
- Charlemagne et Jeanne d’Arc n’étaient PAS contemporains l’un de l’autre. Charlemagne a vécu dans les SEPT cents et Jeanne d’Arc dans les MILLE quatre cents.
- Il ne faut pas confondre con-JEC-ture et con-JONC-ture.

Un autre genre de mise en relief en début de mot est la gémination de la première consonne (on dit qu’il y a dédoublement de celle-ci, mais en fait, c’est plutôt un étirement). Facile à produire pour certains sons (M, N, Z-S, V-F, J-CH), on la rencontre aussi pourtant pour d’autres (D-T, B-P, G-K), pour lesquels la désoclusion de l’air est retardée un instant. Le but visé est à nouveau l’insistance sur le degré important à rattacher au vocable utilisé, mais parfois péjoratif en ce cas:

- Il est mm-échant! *(très méchant...)*
- Il est dd-ébile ou quoi? *(un rare degré de débilité)*
- SS-uper... *(pas super, vraiment pas de quoi en faire un plat)*
  SSU-per! *(là c’est bien!)*
- DD-élicieux... *(mangeable...)*
  DDÉ-licieux! *(exquis!)*

La présence d’un E caduc à la fin d’un mot est une autre modification de la syllabe tonique, qui se fait par contre de manière plus régulière et sans nécessité d’emphase, bien qu’aujourd’hui elle concerne principalement certaines régions de la Francophonie et fort peu d’autres.

- Dos au feu et ventre à TA-bleuh.
- On n’attrapeuh pas des mouches avec du vi-NAI-greuh.

L’accentuation par des étrangers de syllabes de noms propres tels que prononcés dans leur langue d’origine arrive parfois, mais est ressentie comme plutôt étrange et ne fait pas partie de la langue standard:

- BA-rack o-BA-ma est le 44e président des États-Unis.
  *Le français privilégierait plutôt*:
  ba-rack o-ba-MA est le 44e président des États-Unis.

Comment: Intéressant. As-tu des références ? Je continue quand même de m'interroger sur une chose : n'y a-t-il pas des variations entre locuteurs ?

Comment: Il y a toujours le Grevisse comme référence (j’y ai trouvé par exemple la gémination, incluse dans ma réponse), mais je pense qu’un simple test comme tu as fais (radio, s’écouter soi-même, écouter autours de soi) suffit à faire ressortir des différences. Ensuite, il faut voir si les hausses de ton sont significatives et comment elles changent le message. Les gens parlent différemment entre eux et aussi selon la région. Il y a des introvertis et des extravertis. J’ai trouvé des exemples qui me semblent corrects, mais je ne prétends pas que la réponse est complète.