# Does "appe-" as part of the imparfait forms of "appeler" give me one or two syllables?

Tags: prononciation, imparfait

According to [Wiktionary's conjugation table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appeler#Conjugation) (below captured in portions), it would appear that *appe-* in the imparfait forms is one syllable (/a.p/, or strictly speaking one syllable and the consonant sound of the next syllable)  except in the first and the second person plural, wherein it is two syllables (/a.pə/).

[image]

But on the present tense first and the second person plural, the same table assigns but one syllable to *appe-*.

[image]

On Forvo.com too, *appe-* seems to receive one or two syllables on a rather random basis.  For example:

- For [*j'appelais*](https://forvo.com/word/j%27appelais/#fr), Domigloup /a.pə.lɛ/, gwen_bzh both /a.pə.lɛ/ and /a.plɛ/.
- For [*appelait*](https://forvo.com/word/appelait/#fr), /a.pə.lɛ/.
- For [*l'appelait*](https://forvo.com/word/l%27appelait/#fr), /a.pə.lɛ/.
- For [*nous nous appelons*](https://forvo.com/word/nous_nous_appelons/), spl0uf /a.plɔ̃/, huntmdwn /a.plɔ̃/, gwen_bzh (probably) /a.pə.lɔ̃/, Domigloup /a.pə.lɔ̃/.

The question is then:  Based on the above data, am I OK to conclude that I am free to give one or two syllables to *appe-* as occurring in these forms of *appeler*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to analyze a fragment, which will certainly show inconsistency since the rule that affects it operates at word level.

The *e* in the middle of *appeler* is an example of what's called an "[*e* caduc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc)" (also known as muet, facultatif, or instable). The context determines whether it's pronounced or not. When it occurs in the middle of the word, as with *appeler*, its dropping out is an example of [syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology)).

Essentially, this vowel was once or is nominally present in the word, but depending on the stress pattern, which depends on the conjugation, it can be heavily reduced. Reduced vowels tend to drop out; the phenomenon is so natural cross-linguistically that it might have been done in Latin, too.

Dropping it is mostly systematic in French, so I would hesitate to call it a mistake. It would be odd to say « Je vais à-pelle-ai mon frère » instead of « Je vais appler mon frère » !

The stress that affects whether this *e* is reduced is actually not a special case but derives from the rule that the stress falls on the last syllable in French (at least when isolating grammar from [usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30053/accent-en-d%C3%A9but-de-mot-qui-o%C3%B9-et-quand)). In the conjugations that have a syllable after the *e* caduc, said syllable gets the stress. Therefore, the *e* is reduced and liable to be dropped:

> /ap(ə)l-/ **:** appel**on**s, appel**e**z, appel**ai**s, appel**ai**t, appel**ion**s,<sup>1</sup> appel**ie**z, appel**ai**ent
>
> /apɛl/ **:** app**e**lle, app**e**lles, app**e**llent

The same rule covers *lever*, *renouveler*, *acheter*, *amener*, and others.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> In *appelions* and *appeliez*, the *e* can sometimes be heard, as in the conjugation table you quoted. My interpretation of that data is that the onset cluster /.plj/ is pretty unlikely. Phonologically I'm not sure whether the *e* caduc surfaces as a schwa, as in /pə.lj/, or the /p/ is moved to the coda and released, as in /p.lj/ — but phonetically the result would be about the same.</sub>

Comment: Thank you.  (a) Is any degree of "reducing" acceptable for *appelait*? That is, I may use /a.pə.lɛ/ (fully pronouncing a schwa), /a.plɛ/ (dropping it altogether) or anything in between? (b) For *appelions*, am I OK to understand the same (i.e. any degree of reducing is acceptable) subject to the idea that a schwa is more likely to be heard than in *appelait*?--If you tell me that any degree of reducing is OK, I plan to start with a full schwa across the board until I find myself naturally reducing and dropping as appropriate.

Comment: (c) Does the same apply to the futur simple? E.g. *appellerai* is anywhere between /a.pɛ.lə.ʁe/ and /a.pɛl.ʁe/? Wiktionary only gives /a.pɛl.ʁe/. But Forvo.com seems to have varying degrees of "reducing." https://forvo.com/word/appellerai/

Comment: @Catomic (a,b) I'm sure you'll be understood, but the closer to zero, probably the more natural you'll sound. (Maybe a native speaker can confirm.) (c) Good comparison! Notice how the *e* caduc has moved to the vowel before the stress, leaving the one originally under discussion totally unreduced... but yup, as for the new one, it should more or less disappear in normal speech /a.pɛl.ʁe/. Those who are giving it space are, I think, doing it to give a clear pronunciation for the website, much like the second syllable of "[table](https://forvo.com/word/table/#fr)" is unrealistically emphasized.

Comment: @Catomic It really depends on the speakers with who you'll interact. Not dropping a medial schwa between two single consonants like in "appeler" does sound very stilted (it's something you'd normally only do when reading aloud from a text or in very careful speech like on Forvo) to me who's from Belgium and I suspect to Canadians. But French people, even from the North, are in frequent contact  with Southern speakers for who it's normal to produce such /ə/ and probably find it more normal than I do

Answer (score 2):

Actually /a.plɛ/ as a phonemic representation is not really correct. It's a contraction that people make, typically depending on their accent (mostly north part of France I'd say, but nearly everyone makes it sometimes) or speed.

If you are speaking without contraction, appe- is pronounced /a.pə/ or /a.pɛ/, depending on the sound that comes after the 'L'. IIRC ə can be silent, which covers the contraction case.

If there are no sound after the 'L' it's /a.pɛl/ (and written with 2 'L').

Comment: You shouldn't state an accent is "correct" or not. There are just different standard pronunciations just like with other languages. Both /a.plɛ/ and /a.pəlɛ/ are correct French pronunciations for *appelais* and so is the other variants I would personally use: /a.pəle/. Which one will be heard depends on various factors including the one you states: regional accent and speed.

Comment: I did not mean to state the correctness of the accent itself. What I mean is that there is an original prononciation and an evolution of it. /a.pə.lɛ/ encompasses both prononciations and /a.plɛ/ does not. Making it a misleading representation, that's why I said it was "not really correct".

Comment: Ah, I got it. You were referring to the phonetic representation, not the accent itself. Instead of assuming the reader knows that /ə/ might be silent, it might be better to use the clearer /a.p(ə)lɛ/.